# CCAvenue integration with Android-error

Tags: php, android, ccavenue

I am using CCAvenue as a Payment Gateway for my android application. I have registered with CCAvenue and got all the details. The problem I'm facing are

- I'm generating a random 8 digit number for OrderID and passing it to the GetRSA.php file in my server using AsyncTask. Sometimes it works (like once in a day) after that the php file is returning a null value and my app crashes.
- Also I tried transacting a minimum amount when it worked. In my app I got the result as "Status Unknown" whereas it is showing as "Successful" in my CCAvenue dashboard.

My app is not yet live in Playstore, whether that could cause any issue? I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Sorry, of this is a stupid question, as I am new to android as well as for payment gateway.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: please provide code then only we can able to help u @RKM

Comment: what it means minimum amount ..... I did't get it .. can u specify it clearly.